# Does AnimatedList Widget behave like ListView.bulder in terms of storing data in memory with visual content only?

Tags: flutter, dart

I decided to use `AnimatedList Widget` instead of `ListView.bulder Widget` because `AnimatedList Widget` provides me with an amazing animation

my content list contains big data like videos ,images text .. etc and it also big in length

We all know that `ListView.bulder Widget` stores data in memory within the limits of the screen-visible content only. and this good for avoiding memory leek .

Now my question is : Does AnimatedList Widget behave like ListView.bulder in terms of storing data in memory with visual content only? Or does it store all list data in memory and if so what is the best way to do animation back to `ListView.bulder Widget`

Answer (score 0):

> This widget is similar to one created by ListView.builder.

Yes, the [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) behaves similar to [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html). You can check the Example on [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html).
You can add more items in the list by setting the `initialItems` to the following

```
 initialItems: <int>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
```

and add a `print` to the `_buildItem` method.
You will see that the item will only be built, if it is visible.

Comment: But this may not mean that all data is inactive in memory , because if i am not wrong AnimatedList can see any context of it's items even if it is not visible but listview.bulder only can read the visible context  .. no?